# adding a unique id to an url

Tags: ajax, url, unique-id

I have some difficulty in understanding how to add an id to an url for sending a request to a server. In fact, my main problem is the position of quotation mark after the equal sign in the third open method. Why it is not used just after Math.random() or just after .asp. Since, if i place the quotation mark just after math.random(), it works but just before math.random() does not. I want to understand what the quotation mark changes here...

```
xhttp.open(method, url, async);
xhttp.send();

xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.asp", true);
xhttp.send();

**xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.asp?t=" + Math.random(), true);**
xhttp.send();
```

For example, I understand what is happening in the following url.

```
http://localhost/test.php?q=_&p1=_&p2=_
```

`?` lets the server know what the `?_GET` variables start
`q`, `p1`, and `p2` are parameters and `_` is value

Answer (score 0):

The Math.random() function returns a float value. You are actually building up a string. So you need to convert it like so:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.asp?t=" + Math.random().toString(), true);
```

Comment: ``?t=" + ``   why quotation mark is after equal sign. I can not understand this. I got the code from w3schools by the way as below. ``xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.asp?t=" + Math.random(), true);
xhttp.send();``

Answer (score 0):

The `XMLHttpRequest` object `xhttp` sends an asynchronous `GET` request to the server side script `demo_get.asp` with a query string `t`; the value of which is a random number (within the range 0 to 1).

In case of multiple query strings, the query strings are separated using `&`. For example, the `test.php` script you mentioned in your question accepts three query strings: `q`, `p1` and `p2`, values of which are mentioned using `=` symbol. Most importantly, the query string-value pair are separated using `&` symbol.

Comment: I still did not understand why quotation marks "demo_get.asp?t=" here, not at the end of url(just before the comma).

Answer (score 0):

That is because as it will pass a value like this [ url?t=(a random value) ] as a string value. Here the passing value is "demo_get.asp?t= RANDOM_NUMBER". And now coming to your question--------- if the quotation mark is just before the comma like [ "demo_get.asp?t= Math.random()" ] you can see that Math.random() is no more a function. It will become just a string.

Now you can do like that as new javascript has given a mechanism to do that:

Just type demo_get.asp?t= ${Math.random()} (within back-tick(``) as here back tick is not working in comment) instead of [ "demo_get.asp?t=" + Math.random() ]. I hope this helps :)